# Spring Integration SFTP Issue : 2 Too many authentication failures for webadm

Tags: spring, sftp

I am trying to transfer file from one server to another server using SI SFTP adapater. It worked for 1st time. after that I am started getting below error. Can anyone through some light how to resolve it.

[7/18/14 18:05:26:273 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:273 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:273 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:273 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
[7/18/14 18:05:26:274 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:321)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:274 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:74)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:274 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:71)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:274 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:187)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:274 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:167)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:274 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     ... 198 more
[7/18/14 18:05:26:274 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
[7/18/14 18:05:26:275 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:250)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:275 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:316)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:275 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     ... 202 more
[7/18/14 18:05:26:275 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures for webadm
[7/18/14 18:05:26:276 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:987)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:276 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:83)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:276 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:276 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:276 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:241)
[7/18/14 18:05:26:276 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R     ... 203 more

Comment: It is working for 1st time. but very second time onwards I am getting above error. Do anyone know what could be problem here.

Comment: There's hardly any information in your post that can help troubleshooting your problem. Consider posting a log (I assume your client library has logging capability) and also server-side log.